# Increment in denominator in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to make and print a series of the form 1/n; where n is a natural number.

```
int Number;
  float NumberInverse, NumberInverseNext;
  for ( Number = 1; Number < 1000; Number++)
```

if I try to print 'Number' after this, I get a series of natural numbers from 1-1000, as I'd expect. But if I do

```
NumberInverse = 1/Number;
```

and try to print NumberInverse, I get 0 as output. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing.

EDIT : This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned as even after changing

```
 NumberInverse = 1/Number;
```

to

```
NumberInverse = 1/(float)Number;
```

I can't get the series of 1/n which was the original question

Comment: Integer math. Both terms are `int`, so the math is `int`. Widen at least one term first `1/(float)Number;`

Comment: You mention that you cannot get the series of 1/n, but it seems like a trivial error, like misplaced `printf`. To make your question really clear, post the whole code, including any statements that print information. Post also the output you get and the output you want to get. See also this: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting, the answer in your case is an integer so you will get 0, try this:

```
int Number;
  float NumberInverse, NumberInverseNext;
  for ( Number = 1; Number < 1000; Number++) {
  NumberInverse = 1/(double)Number;
  printf("%f \n",NumberInverse);
  }
```

Comment: That prints out the value of 1/999 which I think makes sense because my program first increased the number to 999 and then computed NumberInverse.
How do I get a series of NumberInverse?

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh donnow if i got what you want, see the code now i edited it

Comment: that only prints out "0.001001" which is 1/999 and not the series that I want to print

Comment: did you try it? its a loop so it prints the whole series